# Calculating payment: what kind of rounding should be used?

Tags: ecommerce, money

There are several different methods of [rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding). When developing a website that requires calculating a payment, between promotional codes, sales tax, credit card processing fees, it's possible end up with a total that results in a fraction of a penny.

What kind of rounding should be used when converting the total to two decimal places?

Comment: Round up to the next 1 cent.

Comment: Also calculate everything in cents. You can then skip using floats and use integers instead.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your location.  The [Australian department of commerce has very specific rules for rounding transactions](https://www.commerce.wa.gov.au/consumer-protection/rounding) that differ whether it is cash or credit transaction.

In the US, I find a handful of articles about rounding [such as this case with Chipotle](http://business.time.com/2012/08/30/chipotles-fuzzy-math-why-they-stopped-rounding-customers-out-of-change/).  Based on this, it does not appear that there are US laws that govern it, but that rounding could be a public relations issue if done in a way that seems unfair to consumers.

Rounding using the  "nearest" rule is most widely used.  When exactly half way between two values, round up (the non-scientific rounding method).  This would appear to satisfy the legal requirements that I have found, as well as appearing fair to consumers.